# How to reverse all the words in a file with bash in Ubuntu?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, sed

I would like to reverse the complete text from the file.
Say if the file contains:

```
com.e.h/float
```

I want to get output as:

```
float/h.e.com
```

I have tried the command:

```
rev file.txt
```

but I have got all the reverse output: `taolf/h.e.moc`
Is there a way I can get the desired output. Do let me know. Thank you.
Here is teh link of teh sample file: [Sample Text](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzQ6rtO2VN95TWZ2dlBFZzRrS1U/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible to use Perl?

```
perl -nlE 'say reverse(split("([/.])",$_))'  f
```

This one-liner reverses all the lines of f, according to PO's criteria.

If prefer a less parentesis version:

```
perl -nlE 'say reverse split "([/.])"' f
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `sed` and `tac`:

```
str=$(echo 'com.e.h/float' | sed -E 's/(\W+)/\n\1\n/g' | tac | tr -d '\n')

echo "$str"
float/h.e.com
```

- Using `sed` we insert `\n` before and after all non-word characters.
- Using `tac` we reverse the output lines.
- Using `tr` we strip all new lines.

---

If you have gnu-awk then you can do all this in a single awk command using 4 argument `split` function call that populates split strings and delimiters separately:

```
awk '{
   s = ""
   split($0, arr, /\W+/, seps)
   for (i=length(arr); i>=1; i--)
      s = s seps[i] arr[i]
   print s
}' file
```

For non-gnu awk, you can use:

```
awk '{
   r = $0
   i = 0
   while (match(r, /[^a-zA-Z0-9_]+/)) {
      a[++i] = substr(r, RSTART, RLENGTH) substr(r, 0, RSTART-1)
      r = substr(r, RSTART+RLENGTH)
   }
   s = r
   for (j=i; j>=1; j--)
      s = s a[j]
   print s
}' file
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is awesome solution. I have one more query. Hope you can let me know. If I have a file containing such a pattern and want to reverse it, then how I can do it?

Comment: I have encountered the following error while using your command:
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near ,
awk: line 1: illegal reference to array arr
And let me clear it, I have copied the command from here and pasted on my terminal. Please do not consider this error as my typo mistake. Kindly check the code. Hope to hear from you.

Comment: Sure abubhava. 
I have attached the file to the question edited
I just want to have the domains out of it.
And have a file of GigaBytes, hence gave you a chunk out of it.
Hope this help you find the solution for me.

Comment: I have tried your command. But I get errors on my system. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 64-bits. The errors are as:
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near ,
awk: line 1: illegal reference to array arr
Kindly help me.

Comment: So is there no other way to work with it. Anubhava please let me know.. I expect answer from your end. You have solved my query to the utmost level but it is not yet resolved. Please help me.

Comment: ok try this on Ubuntu: `awk '{r=$0; i=0; while (match(r, /[^[:alnum:]_]+/)) {a[++i] = substr(r, RSTART, RLENGTH) substr(r, 0, RSTART-1); r = substr(r, RSTART+RLENGTH)} s=r; for (j=i; j>=1; j--) s = s a[j]; print s}' file`

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code.

```
echo 'com.e.h/float' |
awk '
  BEGIN{ FS=OFS="/" }
  {
    num=split($1,arr,".")
    val=""
    for(i=num;i>0;i--){
       val=(val?val ".":"") arr[i]
    }
    print $2,val
  }
'
```

Comment: Looks good.. I will try it but not in use right now but whenever it will be useful I will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

For portability, this can be done using any awk (not just GNU) using substrings:

```
$ awk '{
    while (match($0,/[[:alnum:]]+/)) {
      s=substr($0,RLENGTH+1,1) substr($0,1,RLENGTH) s;
      $0=substr($0,RLENGTH+2)
    } print s
  }' <<<"com.e.h/float"
```

This steps through the string grabbing alphanumeric strings plus the following character, reversing the order of those two captured pieces, and prepending them to an output string.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, my friend. But I didn't found the output after running your piece of code. I am using the Ubuntu current version. But I don't know whether it runs in some other version. Do let me know. Also what if I have a file containing the pattern and want to reverse them. Do you have any solution for it? please share your insights.

Comment: @JafferWilson, I'm happy to help. The awk code I provided works for me using both BSD awk on FreeBSD and GNU awk on Ubuntu. What does this do for you instead of working? Do you get an error? What version of awk are you using? (`awk --version` will tell you.) Are you using `bash` as your shell? Without bash, the input redirection in my answer will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk's `split`, splitting from separators `.` and `/`, define more if you wish.

```
$ cat program.awk
{
    for(n=split($0,a,"[./]",s); n>=1; n--)               # split to a and s, use n from split
        printf "%s%s", a[n], (n==1?ORS:s[(n-1)])         # printf it pretty
}
```

Run it:

```
$ echo com.e.h/float | awk -f program.awk 
float/h.e.com
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to run it as one-liner:

```
awk '{for(n=split($0,a,"[./]",s); n>=1; n--); printf "%s%s", a[n], (n==1?ORS:s[(n-1)])}' foo.txt
```

Comment: Dear James, I don't know what this program.awk is. Do let me know. Also tell me if there is a file containing such patterns and I want to reverse the string in it then is it possible to use your solution on it? Do share your understanding.

Comment: `program.awk` is the program I wrote as an solution to your problem. You cut and paste it (part between`{}`s including `{}`s)  to `program.awk` file on your computer and run it like presented above in my solution. The patterns (`com.e.h/float` and such assumed) can be in a separate file, let's call it `foo.txt`. You would then run my program: `awk -f program.awk foo.txt`.

Comment: You could also run it as a one-liner, like: `awk '{# code here}' foo.txt`.

Comment: But why it keep giving 'error: bash: syntax error near unexpected token `(''

Comment: You are using Gnu awk, right? If you are, then most likely you have a typo.

Comment: I have just copied your code and pasted it on my terminal. I have not typed anything. Hence, there isn't any problem of typo. You please check the code once again. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I did. But I don't understand why it is not working or me. Well, let me tell you, I am using Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit. And I don't know whether your command has any problem with the OS I am using.

Comment: Use the one-liner I added.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```bash
echo $(echo ruof eerht owt eno | fmt -1 | tac | rev)
```

returns
`one two three four`

Alternatively:

```bash
echo $(echo ruof eerht owt eno | rev | fmt -1 | tac)
```

returns
`four three two one`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're going for, but this should work.

Using any awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS=FS="/"}
    {print $2,
     substr($1,length($1)) "."
     substr($1,length($1)-2,1) "."
     substr($1,1,3)}' input.txt
```