# How to extract domain from a text file using Ubuntu Command?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, command-line, command-prompt

I have a file of URLs, in the format as shown below:

```
com.blendtuts/S
°=
com.blengineering.www/:http
±=
com.blenheimgang.www/le-porsche-museum-en-details/porsche-museum-3
²=
com.blenheimsi
³=
com.blenkov.www/page/media/18/34/376
´=
com.blentwell.www/bookmarks.php/jackroldan/sp
¸=
com.blentwell.www/tags.php/I
```

The file size is in GigaBytes. Say around 250 GB of the file size.

I was trying to reverse the words in the file and extract only the domains from the text. I tried to make it using Ubuntu OS  terminal commands.
Let me tell you what I have tried:

First I removed the data after “/” using the following command:

```
~$ ex -sc '%s/\(\/\).*/\1/ | x' newfile.txt > ddm.txt
```

And the result as:

```
com.blendtuts/
 °=
com.blengineering.www/
±=
com.blenheimgang.www/
²=
com.blenheimsi
³=
com.blenkov.www/
´=
com.blentwell.www/
¸=
com.blentwell.www/
```

Now I reversed the complete text in the file using the solution from :   [How to reverse all the words in a file with bash in Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40467918/how-to-reverse-the-word-in-ubuntu)

And got the following result:

```
    /blendtuts.com
    °= /www.blengineering.com
    ±= /www.blenheimgang.com
    ²= blenheimsi.com
    ³= /www.blenkov.com
    µ=  /www.blentwell.com
    ¶=  /www.blentwell.com
    •=  /www.blentwell.com

/www.blentwell.com
```

But still the problem is not solved. I would like to how it is possible to extract URLs and put them into another file using Ubuntu. As you can see above the output what still I have is not the domain, it has a backslash with it.

If there is another solution to such a problem using any other operating system, do let me know. I prefer to go with Ubuntu.

I would like to extract domains out of the file and separate them to another file and that too in a proper format.

If I get the unique domain then it will be an excellent solution to my query. Otherwise, I am using command as:

```
$ sort filename.txt | uniq > save_to_file.txt
```

Hope to hear a solution.
Please check here is the sample file: [Sample File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzQ6rtO2VN95TWZ2dlBFZzRrS1U/view)

Comment: can you add complete expected output for sample input shown for clarity including the post processing like sort/uniq

Comment: @Sundeep I think my question is clear. Still, if you want then let me tell you that I have a file containing domain name in reverse format and followed by slash and even some unwanted characters. Just want to extract the domains in a proper format and save it in another file. Hope this help you to understand.

Comment: Having complete expected output helps in testing as well as clear up what is written in text... I've also seen it bring up things not mentioned in writing or overlooked..

Comment: Why anyone downvote without any reason specified. I don't understand the reason behind a downvote..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got this answer:

```
$ perl -F/ -anle 'print reverse(split("([^.]*)", $F[0])) if /\./' file_name.txt
```

One can refer to : https://askubuntu.com/questions/847307/how-to-do-this-in-a-single-command-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: can also use `perl -F/ -lane 'print reverse split /(\.)/, $F[0] if /\./'`

Answer (score 1):

Please consider the following for domain extraction and reversion:

```
awk -F '/' '/com\./ {split($1, arr, /\W+/, seps); for (i=length(arr); i>=1; i--){s = s seps[i] arr[i];} print s ; s="";}'
```

Comment: Using your Code I encountered an error saying:
' awk: line 1: syntax error at or near ,
awk: line 1: illegal reference to array arr
awk: 1: unexpected character '.' '
Please check your code once again.

Comment: I checked it in bash and tcsh on my RHEL 7.1 and saw no problem. Please show how you use it

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit system and just copying and pasting your command on the terminal.

Comment: Your command not working. Please, check it and let me know. I am still getting the same error. If there is any problem from my side please let me know.

Comment: @JafferWilson what is your awk version? this command works for me on `GNU Awk 4.1.3`

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove invalid entries, Mostly we are not interested in lines which starts with ASCII character and ends with character '='
2. We are interested in URL before first /
3. Reverse the URL

I have tried below command on your content which gives the lis of URLs

```
cat -v filename.txt | grep -v '^M-.=' | awk -F '/' '{print $1}' | awk -F '.' 'BEGIN{ORS="";}{ for (i=NF; i>0; i--) if ( i == 1 ) { print $i } else { print $i".";} print "\n"; }'
```

Output

www.blendschutzrollo.com

blendtuts.com

www.blengineering.com

www.blenheimgang.com

.

.

.